# Setting PayPal payments so that they only go through once approved

Tags: paypal, payments, payment-gateway, creditcard

I am thinking of using PayPal standard so that users can pay for membership on a client's website.

However I would like it so that, they user can submit their payment details on PayPal but then for the actual payment to not go through until my client says it's okay (this could be around a week in total).

Is this possible with PayPal? and if so, what is the feature called that I need to research?

Answer (score 1):

I think I may have found the solution:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/authcapture/

Is this correct? Payment gateways aren't my speciality and so it's hard for me to be sure.